# What is a bidifferential operator?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, differential-operators

> Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. Then what is meant by saying that a map $c : C^{\infty} (M) \times C^{\infty} (M) \longrightarrow C^{\infty} (M)$ is a bidifferential operator?

Such terminology has been used by Etingof in his lecture notes on quantum groups without explicitly mentioning what it is actually. Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: A bidifferential operatør is to a diffential operatør what a bilinear operator is to a linear one: a map that is a differential operators with respect to each argument.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez$:$ What is a differential operator on $C^{\infty} (M)$? Differential operators with respect to each argument means what?

Comment: Have you at least googled for a definition?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez$:$ I have searched for it but don't find any result which suits my purpose. I don't know what bothers the members of MSE to explain something clearly when there is a question on basic understanding. They are always busy to either close the question or tag the question as duplicate. This kind of arrogant behavior is simply not acceptable.

Comment: There is a Wikipedia page with title "Differential operator" which includes all the definitions one can give for what a differential operators is — and in various levels of generality — and the usual characterizations. There is really nothing that one could add to what is written there. Being familiar with what you are reading, I can tell you that that is what you are looking for. If your purpose is somewhat different, then it is up to **you** to explain why what is given in easily accessible sources, like Wikipedia, does not suit you. How could we guess?

Comment: Repeating here what someone wrote with evident care on Wikipedia is a waste of effort.